# c multiple file descriptors

Tags: c, file, concatenation

I am trying to make a C program that concatenates the contents of two files at a target file. To do this I must have at least 2 files open at the same time but I haven't figured out why I can't. The problem can be sufficiently described by the two pieces of code below:

Why does this work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    size_t fdes = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    void * buf;
    int bytes;
    while ((bytes = (int)read(fdes, buf, 3)) > 0) {
        printf("%s", (char*)buf);
    }
    close(fdes);
    return 0;
}
```

and this doesn't?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    size_t fdes = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    size_t fdes2 = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY);
    void * buf;
    int bytes;
    while ((bytes = (int)read(fdes, buf, 3)) > 0) {
        printf("%s", (char*)buf);
    }
    close(fdes);
    close(fdes2);
    return 0;
}
```

can't i have multiple files open?

Comment: `buf` is uninitialized, neither version works. You're just getting something different out of undefined behavior.

Comment: also, [`open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) returns an `int` and [`read`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) returns a `ssize_t`.. highly recommend using these correct types and checking the `open` return codes before proceeding.

Comment: You've not allocated space for the buffer (`void *buffer = (char [])"   ";` might work, but it would be more sensible to use `char buffer[4] = "";`).  You never read from the second buffer.  You don't check that anything worked (always check the value returned by `open()`, `fopen()` and their kin), and you don't make sure you have null-terminated information.  You should be using `bytes` in the `printf()` too; `printf("%.*s", bytes, (char *)buf);` — but the need to cast indicates bad design, hence the `char buffer[4]` recommendation.

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking (using `argc`) to assure the command line parameter was actually entered by the user.

Comment: the function: `open()`  returns a `int`, not a `size_t`

Comment: always check (>=0) the returned value from `open()`.  If less than 0, then call `perror( "open failed" );` to output the reason the call failed to `stderr`

Comment: the pointer `buf` is never set to point to some memory that the code owns, so writing to it (via the call to `read()`) is writing to some random location in memory. (what ever trash on the stack at the location of `buf` is being used as a pointer to memory.)  this is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  BTW: the `buf` should be `char` not `void`

Answer (score 0):

I make some changes, and this works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    size_t fdes = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    size_t fdes2 = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY);
    size_t length = 0;
    char * buf = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
    int bytes;

    while ((bytes = (int)read(fdes, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1)) > 0) {
        printf("%s", buf);
    }

    while ((bytes = (int)read(fdes2, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1)) > 0) {
        printf("%s", buf);
    }
    close(fdes);
    close(fdes2);
    return 0;
}
```

First, `buf` should be `char *`

Second, you need to point `buf` to somewhere (`malloc` or a `char array`)

Reference: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/rtrea.htm

Comment: Ooof.  `size_t length = 0;` and then `malloc(sizeof(char) * length);`?  `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1 always, and that's a zero-byte buffer, if it doesn't return `NULL`.  Given `char * buf`, just what do you think `sizeof(buf)` returns?  And `read()` does not produce a `NUL`-terminated string value.

Comment: I meant to set `length` to 0. Why? Because the program still runs well, and I'm waiting for some guy to explain why. And what is the problem with `read()`?